# AngularJS Controllers - messy scope boolean values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Although my controllers in my AngularJS app are working, I feel they are very messy, hard to maintain and I'm doing something wrong.

In my example, I have two search boxes: `ip` and `port`. When validated, these are sent via a POST request and check whether the server exists.

Based on the response, I show a message along with a `success`, `warning` or `error` scope boolean value to trigger what class/colour will be shown.

This works fine, however I will have more validation with more user input boxes afterwards, which means more variables and more mess. Here's an example:

```
    $scope.server = {};

    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.successRcon = false;

    $scope.warning = {};
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.errorRcon = false;

    $scope.message = false;
    $scope.messageRcon = false;

    $scope.warning.main = false;
    $scope.warning.ip = false;
    $scope.warning.port = false;

    $scope.searching = false;
    $scope.found = false;

    $scope.adding = false;
    $scope.addUserError = false;

    $scope.validating = false;

    $scope.search = function(server)
    {
        if (! angular.isDefined(server.ip) || ! validateIp(server.ip))
        {
            $scope.success = false;
            $scope.warning.main = true;

            $scope.warning.ip = true;
            $scope.error = false;

            $scope.searching = false;

            $scope.message = 'Please enter a valid IP address!';
        }
        else if(! angular.isDefined(server.port) || ! validateNumber(server.port))
        {
            $scope.success = false;
            $scope.warning.main = true;

            $scope.warning.ip = false;
            $scope.warning.port = true;
            $scope.error = false;

            $scope.searching = false;

            $scope.message = 'Please enter a valid port number!';
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.success = false;
            $scope.warning.main = false;
            $scope.error = false;

            $scope.warning.ip = false;
            $scope.warning.port = false;

            $scope.searching = true;

            $scope.message = false;

            // http post request, the response also sets some of these values
       }
   };
```

As you can see, this is pretty horrendous.. Any solution to doing something like this?

Comment: What is messageRcon, successRcon and errorRcon. They are not being set in any other if statement.

Comment: Sorry they're used in the feedback of the http post request.

Answer (score 0):

In order to minimize the code and make it more maintainable you can have only errorStatus,ErrorCode and errorMessage variables and set either the strings ip, port or nothing to make it more maintainable something like this:

```
 $scope.server = {};
 $scope.warning = {};

    $scope.errorStatus = '';
    $scope.errorCode = [];

    $scope.successRcon = false;
    $scope.errorRcon = false;  
    $scope.messageRcon = false;


    $scope.search = function(server)
    {
        if (! angular.isDefined(server.ip) || ! validateIp(server.ip))
        {
            $scope.errorStatus = 'warning';
            $scope.errorCode.push({'errorType':'ip'});
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid IP address!';
        }
        else if(! angular.isDefined(server.port) || ! validateNumber(server.port))
        {
            $scope.errorStatus = 'warning';
            $scope.errorCode.push({'errorType':'main'});
            $scope.errorCode.push({'errorType':'port'});
            $scope.message = 'Please enter a valid port number!';
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.errorStatus = 'success';
            // http post request, the response also sets some of these values
       }
   };
```